# With 40 credits, can I still be eligible to receive social security benefits at age 67 IF I LOSE MY permanent resident status?

Tags: united-states, social-security

I know there are similar questions here, but my case is a bit special so I ask this question.

I have been working in the U.S. for 10 years and accumulated 40 social security credits.
Now, I and my wife have green cards but we are not going to have U.S. citizenships.
We consider working in another country next year, so that we are likely to lose our green cards within the next few years.

Given that we already earned 40 credits, can we still be eligible for social security benefits at 67?

Comment: See https://www.ssa.gov/ssi/text-eligibility-ussi.htm. There isn't enough information in the question to determine if you do or will qualify.

Comment: @chepner The information at that link is for Supplemental Security Income, which is not the same as regular social security retirement benefits.

Comment: I'm going to lean toward you are still eligible, but haven't found ssa.gov documentation beyond the fact that there is a program for [Nonresident Alien Tax Withholding](https://www.ssa.gov/international/AlienTax.html), as if you lose your green card and leave the US you'll become a [non-resident alien under the IRS](https://www.ssa.gov/international/AlienTax_reference_2.html). You may wish to  contact the [SSA directly](https://www.ssa.gov/foreign/index.html).

Comment: Also, does your home country have a Social Security treaty with the US?  If so, my understanding (though I'm by no means an expert) is that US Social Security taxes would apply towards benefits from your home country: https://www.ssa.gov/international/agreements_overview.html